# Unable to apply django migrations to postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My django project earlier used sqlite, but now we have changed it to use Postgresql. Here are the new settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'vader',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I have created a db vader and user root as its owner. Now, when I try to apply migrations with:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get the following error:

```
(env1)sushil@Linux-Machine:~/Adomattic/Vader$ python manage.py migrate
    [profile] heap size is 22.5 MB
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 63, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 184, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.get_table_list(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 165, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 138, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 134, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/sushil/Adomattic/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

It is saying no password supplied, but I am not sure where to pass the password. Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Comment: In your database config is an empty field called `PASSWORD`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your database user password to your `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'vader',
        'USER': 'root',

        # Add password here 
        'PASSWORD': '',


        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: which password? the db i created - vader, has no password

Comment: @BeginnersClub the root password. You should have a user and a password.

Comment: yes i created a user root, but without any password. ex: createuser root

Comment: Try to create a user other than root and give it the privileges to use the database, then paste the new information in you settings

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `PASSWORD`, `HOST` and `PORT` like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'vader',
        'USER': 'root'
    }
}
```

Then do the migrate again.